# postgresql - insert result of query SELECT EXTRACT into another table

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table in postgresql (table1):

```
 Var1,
 var2,
 var3,
 timestamp1  timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
 timestamp2  timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
 diff double precision,
```

The column diff is empty.

I calculate the variable diff  by the following code:
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ((timestamp1 – timestamp2)/1800))

I want insert the result of this operation in variable diff of table 1.

I write the following code, but do not work…

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temptablename AS
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ((timestamp1 – timestamp2)/1800)) AS diff2 from table1;

INSERT INTO table1 (diff) SELECT diff2 FROM temptablename;

ERROR:  null value in column "" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, null, null, null, null,83).
```

Comment: Well what do you expect? You are trying to insert null into columns that are defined as `not null`

Comment: thank you Mike Sherrill 'Cat Recall'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your arithmetic is right, it *sounds* like you just need an update statement.

```
update table1
set diff = extract(epoch from ((timestamp1 – timestamp2)/1800))
where diff is null;
```

The WHERE clause isn't strictly necessary, since you already know that column is empty. But it guards against overwriting values the *second* time you run that statement.